# NoSuchMethodError when the method obviously exists

Tags: java, mysql, bukkit

```
20:15:43 [INFO] macintosh264 issued server command: /sell hand
20:15:43 [INFO] [XYZShop] MacCommand sell executed
20:15:43 [SEVERE] null
org.bukkit.command.CommandException: Unhandled exception executing command 'sell' in plugin XYZShop v0.1.3
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:46)
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:186)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:510)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.PlayerConnection.handleCommand(PlayerConnection.java:979)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.PlayerConnection.chat(PlayerConnection.java:897)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:852)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.Packet3Chat.handle(Packet3Chat.java:44)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:290)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.PlayerConnection.d(PlayerConnection.java:112)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.ServerConnection.b(SourceFile:39)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServerConnection.b(SourceFile:30)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.r(MinecraftServer.java:598)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServer.r(DedicatedServer.java:224)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.q(MinecraftServer.java:494)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:427)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:849)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: dev.xyzcraft.net.database.DatabaseHandler.getItem(IS)Ldev/xyzcraft/net/xyzshop/dataObject/MSItem;
        at dev.xyzcraft.net.xyzshop.commands.SellCommand.onCommand(SellCommand.java:63)
        at dev.xyzcraft.net.xyzshop.util.MacCommand.onCommand(MacCommand.java:44)
        at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:44)
        ... 15 more
```

I get that exception

here's the code:
https://github.com/macintosh264/XYZShop

Lastly, I'm using a Mod API for a popular video game, Minecraft, entitled Bukkit. Here's the JavaDoc, and library

http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/bukkit/

http://jd.bukkit.org

"I also have this problem with another project that uses MySQL, and the stack trace occurs WHENEVER the mysql class is used. "

- Macintosh264

Comment: How do you know that it obviously exists? Are you checking the _Java byte code_?

Comment: make sure that you don't have multiple versions of the library you are using.

Comment: I don't think I have multiple versions. I'll double check. I also have this problem with another project that uses MySQL, and the stack trace occurs WHENEVER the mysql class is used.

Comment: http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/fe/62/fe62a0a70c41fd4f08b689ab4a425767.png
Seems I don't. Looked in NetBeans (used to use eclipse, but I find NetBeans easier to use when importing open source projects)

Comment: This error happens when you compile against a version that has the method and execute with a version that doesn't. You wouldn't be able to compile without the first version, and you wouldn't get the error without the second version. Ergo, you have two versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like whatever your trying to execute (i.e.the method that holds the command) isn't reading it properly. Try re-packaging your project, it's happened to me many times and that is usually an easy fix.