# How can I resolve the NoSuchMethodError caused by firebase' `subscribeToTopic`?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I have a mostly android/java runtime issue happening in a react-native project. I don't think that react-native has anything to do with the issue, but may be helpful to understand the code or errors involved. I've been getting the error below:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke RNFIRMessaging.subscribeToTopic

That is coming out of the react-native framework. The try-catch in the method doesn't catch the error, but the code does execute all the way up to the point where `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic);` is invoked.

This is the internal error that is the real culprit:

> ... Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method subscribeToTopic(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging' appears in ...

This is the code that corresponds to `RNFIRMessaging.subscribeToTopic`:

```
public class FIRMessagingModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements LifecycleEventListener, ActivityEventListener {
   ...
   @Override
   public String getName() {
       return "RNFIRMessaging";
   }
   ...
   public void subscribeToTopic(String topic) {
     try {
         Log.w("MYFCM", "Trying to call subscribeToTopic");
         FirebaseMessaging x = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
         if (x == null)
             Log.w("MYFCM", "hasinstance?: NO");
         else {
             Log.w("MYFCM", "hasinstance?: YES");
             // use reflection to print the methods
             Class c = x.getClass();
             for (java.lang.reflect.Method method : c.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                 Log.w("MYFCM", "methods: " + method.getName());
             }
         }
         FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic);
     } catch(Exception ex) {
         Log.e("MYFCM", ex.getMessage());
     }
   }
   ...
}
```

This produces the following log output from `adb logcat`. Note how reflection seems to think the `subscribeToTopic` method exists.

```
05-29 12:21:46.760  8188  8261 W MYFCM   : Trying to call subscribeToTopic
05-29 12:21:46.760  8188  8261 W MYFCM   : Trying hasinstance?: YES
05-29 12:21:46.760  8188  8261 W MYFCM   : methods: getInstance
05-29 12:21:46.760  8188  8261 W MYFCM   : methods: isAutoInitEnabled
05-29 12:21:46.760  8188  8261 W MYFCM   : methods: send
05-29 12:21:46.760  8188  8261 W MYFCM   : methods: setAutoInitEnabled
05-29 12:21:46.760  8188  8261 W MYFCM   : methods: subscribeToTopic
05-29 12:21:46.760  8188  8261 W MYFCM   : methods: unsubscribeFromTopic
05-29 12:21:46.761  8188  8261 E unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
05-29 12:21:46.761  8188  8261 E unknown:ReactNative: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke RNFIRMessaging.subscribeToTopic
```

I suspect my gradle files may be in-scope for this problem:

/android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
...
}
ext {
    targetSdkVersion            = 25
    compileSdkVersion           = 25
    buildToolsVersion           = "27.0.3"
    googlePlayServicesVersion   = "15.0.2"
    firebaseVersion             = "15.0.2"
    supportLibVersion           = "25.4.0"
    reactNativeVersion          = "0.53.3"
}
```

/android/app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseVersion") { force = true }
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseVersion") { force = true }
    implementation("com.android.support:exifinterface:$supportLibVersion") { force = true }
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:$googlePlayServicesVersion") { force = true }
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$googlePlayServicesVersion") { force = true }
...
}
...
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

If it matters, I'm using [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm).  The code snippet above is modified code from that repository.

Prior research:

- I don't think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42864427/567493) is applicable since the `force = true` should prevent multiple copies of firebase from floating around.
- I don't this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096716/567493) is applicable since this is infinitely repeatable (even if I blow away everything and re-clone the project)
- Some similar questions mention proguard. Proguard is disabled (`minifyEnabled false`)

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having exactly the same issue, it's related to a new release of firebase (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180523)

I was able to fix it (temporarily) by modifying the file in the react native fcm library:

> ./node_modules/react-native-fcm/android/build.gradle

There you have to replace:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
```

by the specific version you want to use, in your case I think it's 15.0.2 so it should be:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

This will prevent using the latest version of the libraries by specifying the version you need.